# Vs2010 font color

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, colors

Hey,
I'm a vs2010 user but on my fresh install, the functions/methods are not colored (standard black).
It's silly but I'm so used to it that I miss that little feature. I've looked through the font and colors options but I can't find what I need to change.

And I really don't want to install visual assist.

Any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Identifer you are looking for.

Tools > Options

[image: Example of fonts and colors]

Also check out [studiostyles](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/) for a nice online customization of VS which you can then import via 'Tools > Import and Export Settings'

Comment: Identifier changes the color of everything, attributes too. I just want to color functions/methods (ToString() for example, as well as my custom methods)

Comment: I used to have them darkred =o

Comment: You'd better tell him what dialog to use.  "Identifier" isn't enough.